# Button change number in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, button

I have a website where I list the store products and want start a make orders.
However, for begins, I need change the numbers of the each one.

My code is:

```
$run_produtos = mysqli_query($con,$get_produtos);

while($row_produtos=mysqli_fetch_array($run_produtos)){
    
                $id = $row_produtos['id'];
                $categoria = $row_produtos['categoria'];
                $foto = $row_produtos['foto'];
                $nome = $row_produtos['nome'];
                $descricao = $row_produtos['descricao'];
                $preco = $row_produtos['preco'];

            echo "
                <div style='text-align: left;''>
                    <center>
                            <img src='produtos/$foto' style='width: 200px; height: auto; border: 2px solid grey'>
                            <h3>$nome</h3>
                            <h4>$descricao</h4>
                            <h3>Valor: R$ $preco</h3>

<form>

<input style='font-size: 20px;' type='button' onclick='decreaseValue()' value='-' />
<input style='font-size: 20px; width: 70px; text-align: center;' type='text' id='number' value='$number'/>
<input style='font-size: 20px;' type='button' onclick='incrementValue()' value='+' />

</form>

</center>
<hr>
                        </div>
                <br>
                ";
}
```

And the button code is:

```
<script>
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
function decreaseValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
</script>
```

The button works! The problem is that his changes the numbber only in the first product. I guess that I need indexed this products, but when I try, the website shows only one product.

Please, what I do make?

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't have multiple `id='number'`; if you do, `document.getElementById('number')` always returns the first one. You need to give each item a different ID and pass that as an argument to `incrementValue()`. Or use DOM navigation methods to increment or decrement the button next to the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the duplicate `id='number'` so they're unique by including `$id` in it.

Also add a hidden input that contains `$id`. The form-processing code can use `$id = $_POST['id'];` to get this value.

```
$run_produtos = mysqli_query($con,$get_produtos);

while($row_produtos=mysqli_fetch_array($run_produtos)){
    
    $id = $row_produtos['id'];
    $categoria = $row_produtos['categoria'];
    $foto = $row_produtos['foto'];
    $nome = $row_produtos['nome'];
    $descricao = $row_produtos['descricao'];
    $preco = $row_produtos['preco'];

    echo "
          <div style='text-align: left;''>
              <center>
                  <img src='produtos/$foto' style='width: 200px; height: auto; border: 2px solid grey'>
                  <h3>$nome</h3>
                  <h4>$descricao</h4>
                  <h3>Valor: R$ $preco</h3>

                  <form>
                      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id">
                      <input style='font-size: 20px;' type='button' onclick='decreaseValue($id)' value='-' />
                      <input style='font-size: 20px; width: 70px; text-align: center;' type='text' id='number$id' value='$number'/>
                      <input style='font-size: 20px;' type='button' onclick='incrementValue($id)' value='+' />
                  </form>
              </center>
              <hr>
          </div>
          <br>
                ";
}
```

Then change the JS so it uses the `id` argument.

```
<script>
function incrementValue(id)
{
    var el = document.getElementById('number'+id)
    var value = parseInt(el.value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    el.value = value;
}
function decreaseValue()
{
    var el = document.getElementById('number'+id)
    var value = parseInt(el.value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    el.value = value;
}
</script>
```

You could also `<input type='number'>` instead. Most browsers will generate `+/-` controls in the input, so you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: Now, in the next time, exists some way from transfor this value in a php array?
I need send this numbers to a chart file.

Comment: It will be sent to PHP when you submit the form. Or use AJAX to send to PHP without reloading. Read tutorials on form processing in PHP.